# Are the JSON arrays LL(1) parsable?

Tags: json, grammar, lex

I've heard if you parse something LL(1) it's faster so I was wondering if you want to parse a JSON string can this be done by using a LL(1) parser

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are, since there's no ambiguity in the JSON grammar.

Comment: In addition, you can check out [my implementation](https://github.com/H2CO3/libjsonz/blob/master/src/jsonz.c) which is hopefully not too difficult to understand.

Comment: While it's true that JSON is LL(1), this answer implies that all non-ambiguous grammars are LL(1).  This is not correct.  LL(1) grammars are a subset of the non-ambiguous grammars.  For example, left-recursive grammars like "A -> A a | a" are not LL(1).

Comment: @JoshHaberman It is my understanding that simple transformations on a left-recursive grammer will make it LL(1).

Comment: @JoshHaberman any reference tha JSON is LL(1)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. See to yourself that the implementation of a parser for JSON string can be done with a automaton consisting of no more than 1 token. In other words, there exists a Markov chain solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

> array:
>
> [ ] |   [ elements ]
>
> elements:
>
> value |   value , elements
>
> it seems not LL(1) to me. Clear cannot parse on "value"

What if this way?

```
array: [ array1 ]
array1: <eps> | elements
elements: value elements1
elements1: <eps> | , elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is LL(1) parsable. It has a context-free grammar and no ambiguity.

Comment: That doesn't make it LL(1).

Comment: A grammar is LL(1) if an LL(1) parser can be constructed for it.  Not all unambiguous context-free grammars have LL(1) parsers.  Sorry if I'm struggling a little here, but I'm not sure what else to say other than to direct you to the Wikipedia page for [LL_parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)

Answer (score 0):

array:

```
[] |
[ elements ]
```

elements:

```
value |
value , elements
```

it seems not `LL(1)` to me. Clear cannot parse on "value"